# Prototype cells not coming up in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am following the FoodTracker App tutorial on the Apple Developer site, and have gotten to the section on Table Views (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH8-SW1).  Everything has worked for me until this lesson.

I went through my code and compared it to the Apple-provided templates.  Everything looks the same, but my Meal Table Views (Prototype cells) are not coming up.

Any help would be appreciated, and I am happy to provide more information if needed.  Thanks!

Comment: In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` have you casted the reusable cell to `MealTableViewCell` (`as! MealTableViewCell`)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment; however, I have let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier  (cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MealTableViewCell .  I am looking at the source code that is provided at the end, and our code is exactly the same.  I could just go on with the provided code, but I would like to know how to approach such problems should they occur in a non-tutorial environment.